# Problem accessing struct via double pointer

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and still understanding how pointers work. Basically i have a class in a header file in which i s defined a strct. Defining the methods in a separate cpp file, i need to access the members of that struct in order to initialize them. In the class i have defined a double pointer of the struct type. IN the class constructor i create an array of those pointers and in the add method i create a struct for the specific element of the pointer array. The problem is right after because i'm not able to access the struct members. In the previous exercise i did this kind of logic worked but i only had to use structures, not classes, so i don't really know. Suggestions?

this is the header file with the class declaration, the double pointer is at the end

```
#ifndef Event_h
#define Event_h

class Event {

public:

 // constructor
  Event( int n, float x, float y, float z ); // create an event with number "n"                                                  // and coordinates x, y, z
 // destructor
 ~Event();

 // composite object Particle to hold all information for each particle
 // ( electric charge and x,y,z momentum components )
 struct Particle {
   int Charge;
   float P_x, P_y, P_z;
 };
 typedef const Particle* part_ptr;

// add a particle to the event
void add( int charge, float px, float py, float pz ); //APPEND A PARTICLE TO THE EVENT

// get event id.
int eventNumber() const; //int function(parameters) const
                       //function is a method which does not modify any of 
                       //the member variables in the object instance for which it is being invoked.
// get decay point coordinates
float x() const;
float y() const;
float z() const;
// get number of particles
int nParticles() const;
// get particle
part_ptr particle( unsigned int i ) const; //funzione

private:

// event-specific informations:
int evNumber; // event id
int nParticles_; //number of particles of the event
float x_, y_, z_; // decay point

// particles: number and array of pointers
static const int max=10; //perché è necessario static const
part_ptr *ptrParticle;

};

#endif
```

this are the method definitions:

```
#include "Event.h"

// constructor
Event::Event( int n, float x, float y, float z ):
// initializations
evNumber(n), x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {
// allocate a buffer for particle pointers
ptrParticle = new Particle*[max];
}


// destructor 
Event::~Event() {
// delete all the particle pointers
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
//delete[] ptrParticle[i]; //???

// delete the pointers array
delete[] ptrParticle;
}


void Event::add( int charge, float px, float py, float pz ) {

// check for the number of particles, if maximum reached do nothing
// and return
// create the new particle and fill with data
if(nParticles_ < max)
{

  ptrParticle[nParticles_] = new Particle;
  //int size = sizeof(ptrParticle);
  *(ptrParticle[nParticles_])->Charge = charge; //the problems are hereeeeee!
  *(ptrParticle[nParticles_])->P_x = px;


 // store the new particle pointer in the array and increase counter
 //...
 ++nParticles_;  
}
return;
}
```

The error it gives is "operand of '*' must be a pointer but has type "int""

i looked up for similar problems in forums, and also, just fo desperation, different uses of the dereferencing operator, i tried to use a single pointer, just a bit of everything, but i really don't understand what's wrong.
Also

- i saw that someone uses malloc, and the professor didn't really covered that, so if there's a way   that doesn't involve it;
- we don't use the vector class yet

Comment: `(*(ptrParticle[nParticles_])).Charge` or `ptrParticle[nParticles_]->Charge` should work. Often the full error message will give you a hint or at least show the types involved.

Comment: You are definitely right to stay away from `malloc` in c++. Even `new` should be avoided later when you have better tools, but it's OK to use them for now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,, unfortunately both statemens return the error "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" :\

Comment: @Silver That's where you learn that `typedef const Particle* part_ptr;` is a bad idea for multiple reasons.

Comment: you are trying to modify a `const` object, remove the `const`.

Comment: And maybe try a `std::vector<Particle>` instead of all the pointers and allocations. Would solve a lot of your problems.

Comment: If you're new to C++ avoid using double pointers altogether. Current C++ recommends not to use raw pointers/new/delete (unless you're writing the internals of a datastructure). There are containter (std::vector, std::map, etc.) and there is std::make_unique/std::make_shared. Investigate those first.

Comment: You are certainly on the wrong track. Raw pointers are reserved for ultra-expert seniors. Double pointers have no place in well-designed code, even if used by experts. If you want to get frustrated by C++, you're welcome digging into raw pointers as a beginner.

Comment: For people warning about raw pointers: The OP explicitly told they don't use vectors yet. And I agree that raw pointers is not the right target, but I also think it's a good way of learning C++, just because you get what's going on in the inners of the std libs.

Answer (score 1):

```
*(ptrParticle[nParticles_])->Charge = charge; //the problems are hereeeeee!
```

`ptrParticle` is a

```
part_ptr *ptrParticle;
```

So, according to rules of C++, `ptrParticle[nParticles_]` would be a `part_ptr`, which is a

```
const Particle*
```

So, dereferencing this using the `->` operator, in the expression, accesses a `Charge`, which is an `int`. There are two problems with the shown code.

1. Since this is a `const` pointer, this is going to be `const int`. You cannot assign anything to a `const` object, according to the rules of C++.
2. Additionally, the unary `*` cannot be applied to an `int`, this is not allowed in C++ either. This would be equivalent, for example, to:

```
int n;

*n = 4;
```

Obviously, this is sheer nonsense.

Taking a step back:

```
ptrParticle[nParticles_] = new Particle;
```

Since `ptrParticle` is an array of pointers to ***constant*** objects, as soon as you stuff something in there you will automatically forfeit every right to change anything in that object, until the heat death of our universe. That's what a ***constant*** object means in C++.

To do this correctly you must do the following sequence of events.

1. Use `new` to create a new `Particle` object, and store it in a pointer.
2. Initialize this object. Set its `Charge`, using the pointer, to whatever you want to set it do. Set anything else in that object, that you want to set.
3. Store the pointer to the `new`-ed object in this array ***after*** the object is initialized.

Comment: Thank you very much! now it seems to work